# Bad character in identifier in GHDL

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I'm trying to compile the following component in GHDL in Ubuntu 17.10. This is the code of the component:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all; -- Unsigned

entity simple is end simple;
architecture behaviour of simple is
    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal sigterm : std_logic := '0';
    signal counter : unsigned(7 downto 0) := x"00";
begin
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 us;
        clkloop : loop
            wait for 1 us;
            clk <= not clk;
            if sigterm = '1' then
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop clkloop;
        wait for 5 us;
        wait;
    end process;

    process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if counter = 16 then
                sigterm <= '1';
            end if;
            counter <= counter + 1;
        end if;
    end process;
end behaviour;
```

I'm getting this error message while elaborating the component:

```
ghdl:*command-line*: bad character in identifier
```

I'm using the following flags in order to make the commands work in my 64-bits machine, I don't know if they are totally OK:

```
ghdl -a -Wa,--32 -Wl,--32 simple.vhdl
ghdl -e -Wa,--32 -Wl,--32 simple.vhdl
```

Comment: what does `ghdl --version` report? With ghdl-0.35(gcc backend), `ghdl -a simple,vhd` and `ghdl -e simple` just work here (Debian Stretch) but adding those flags gives: `ghdl -a -Wa,--32 simple.vhd
simple.s: Assembler messages:
simple.s:59: Error: bad register name %rbp simple.s:62: Error: bad register name %rsp` Not surprising given 32 bit flags on a 64 bit machine. Adding -m32 to the flags fixes that (but correctly reports I don't have the standard libraries built for 32 bit archs)

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration error message: what is expected here is the name of a design unit, not a file name, plus, if it is not the default `work`, the name of the library.

```
ghdl -a -Wa,--32 -Wl,--32 simple.vhdl
ghdl -e -Wa,--32 -Wl,--32 simple
```

Or, if you compile `simple.vhdl` in library `foolib`:

```
ghdl -a -Wa,--32 -Wl,--32 --work=foolib simple.vhdl
ghdl -e -Wa,--32 -Wl,--32 --work=foolib simple
```

Comment: The period is the unexpected character. In newer versions of ghdl  the name of the design unit being elaborated can be in the form of a selected name and the error messages even more obscure - `*command line*:1:1:error: cannot find resource library "simple" error: cannot find entity or configuration vhdl`, where the period serves as a delimiter.